# Remove old commits and just keep latest commit on REMOTE

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-bash

Think that I have 50 commits on remote and before creating merge request I would like to delete all 49 ones and keep the last one I pushed only.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You want to get rid of all the other changes, or do you only want one commit of all the changes?

Comment: not changes i want to delete all 49 old commits from remote not locally, and just keep the latest pushed commit. @crashmstr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess these 50 commits are in your branch.

I also assume that your branch is based on a parent branch (e.g. `master`), in which it is requested to be merged (with the merge request).

If so and if you want these 50 commits to be one, you can do:

```
git rebase --interactive master # change master if it is not your base branch
```

In the editor which will be open, mark the commits 2 to 50 as `squash` instead of `pick`, Save and quit, Update the commit message to have the one you want, and your commits will be all squashed into one.

If you want the commits 1 to 49 to disappear (including their content) and keep only the 50th), in the editor when running `git rebase --interactive master`, delete all the lines you don't want to keep just the last commit, then save and quit.

At the end you will have to push force to update the remote:

```
git push --force
```

Please also read the `INTERACTIVE MODE` section of:

```
man git-rebase
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity and for extra information, where you trying to `squash` or remove the commits?

Comment: yes like from a branch i was trying to remove the commits not the main master branch.

Comment: Git commands are some of the dumbest annoying nonsense I've ever come across in the software world.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to destroy any history and keep the latest one, just delete `.git` folder and start over.

```
rm -rf .git
git init
git add .
git commit -am "first commit"
```

Of course you will need to re-add submodules, git-config or any short of hooks that were present inside your previous git folder.